# Write a function that reports the number of a's and b's in a file. Then print a statement indicating if there are more a's or b's

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Define compareabinfile(filename) function in a python file compareabinfile.py Your function should first report the number of 'a's and the number of 'b's contained in the file. Your function should then print a statement indicating whether there are more a's than b's (or vice versa) or if there are equal numbers of them.

We were given this code:

```
# After completing your compareabinfile.py file, run this Cell to test it.
# You should only Run this Cell and should not make any changes in this Cell.
import os;
if os.path.exists('compareabinfile.py'):
    import compareabinfile
    compareabinfile.compareabinfile('compareabinfile.py')
```

This is what I have but it is not returning anything when I run the first set of code:

```
def compareabinfile (filename):
    from collections import Counter
    a = filename.count('a')
    return a
    b = filename.count ('b')
    return b
    if a > b:
        print('More A')
        return
    elif b > a:
        print('More B')
        return
    else:
        print('Equal A and B')
        return
```

I'm not getting any errors so I am not sure where my problem is.

Comment: Your function won't do anything after the first `return` statement. You're also counting the number of `"a"` characters in the `filename`, not in the file; you need to open the file first, then count the characters you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def compareabinfile(filename):
    from collections import Counter
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        filedata = f.read()
    a = filedata.count('a')
    print(a)
    b = filedata.count ('b')
    print(b)
    if a > b:
        print('More A')
    elif b > a:
        print('More B')
    else:
        print('Equal A and B')
    return (a,b)
```

The given function returns a tuple with number of `a`s and `b`s in the given file.
The mistake you were doing was the

1. return statement after   `a = filename.count('a')` and `b = filename.count('b')`. That caused the function to end at the same point.
2. you were counting the `a`s and `b`s in the filename and not in the files actual contents.

Comment: Thank you this was super helpful!

Comment: @AllyHohman if your issue is resolved you can accept this answer. thank you